# Custom File Cur for Cusor in C#

Tags: c#, cursor

I want to custom my Cursor on my Form in C#.
I created one file Cur, but don't know change it. How do you change it?

I want to load file .gif to .cur file??

Could you help me.! Thank very must>!

Answer (score 0):

First it needs to be in a .cur format. A [quick search](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=gif%20to%20cur#/search?q=convert%20a%20gif%20to%20cursor&qs=n&sk=&form=QBRE&prevver=search&shash=1) will get give you what you need to make a .gif into a .cur

Once you have your .cur file, just load it in and set the Cursor.

```
Cursor myCursor = new Cursor("myCustomCursor.cur");
this.Cursor = myCursor; //this can be whatever...a textbox, the form, a button. Pretty much anything that is a control
```